# Como remover arquivos locais(untracked files) do meu ramo(branch) atual no Git?

Tags: git

Como remover esses arquivos do meu ramo(branch) atual no Git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É preciso marcar um arquivo para deleção com o comando abaixo

```
git rm <file>
```

Executando o comando abaixo verifica-se que o arquivo está marcado como *deleted*:

```
git status
```

Agora é só efetivar a remoção fazendo o commit:

```
git commit -am "Removido arquivo..."
```

Comment: @Walter, você já fez essa pergunta aqui? Se não... cria uma, para não misturarmos dentro da pergunta feita acima!

Answer (score 5):

Se o arquivos estão no estado `Untracked` significa que o `git` ainda não tem eles sob versionamento.

Podes utilizar o seguinte comando:

```
git clean -f
```

Ou deletar os arquivos manualmente com seu programa preferido, por exemplo comando `rm` na linha de comando.

Vale ressaltar que depois de apagado não terá como reverter, afinal o arquivo **nunca** esteve sob versionamento.

Se o arquivos estão versionados no git então a resposta correta é do [@Brandão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/62543/18743)

Answer (score 1):

Mostra os arquivos que serão removidos:

```
git clean -dnf
```

Remove os arquivos untrackeds

```
git clean -df
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode consultar a documentação em https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm

```
git rm arquivo.txt
```

após isto basta dar um commit para confirmar a remoção

```
git commit -a -m "Exclusao do arquivo.txt"
```